# Horizontal scroll bar causes vertical scroll bar to come when using css Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an HTML structure like below,
The problem is when the horizontal scroll bar is visible, vertical scroll bar starts to come in chrome. But in firefox it is working fine, this is because of div height is not auto-scaling since using the grid 1fr. if I use `height: 100%`, it is working fine.

Here is then [code pen](https://codepen.io/saravananr/full/xeydKR)

```css
html, body {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-row: 1fr 1fr;
}

.mainContainer{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;  
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.box{
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
   <h3>Without horizontal scroll - no vertical scroll bar</h3>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainContainer">
   <h3>With horizontal scroll- vertical scroll is comming</h3>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you remove the div-4, div-5, vertical scrollbar won't come. I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: The 1st issue I can see is that you're giving all your `.container`s `overflow-y: scroll;`. Basically, the vertical scroll show everytime (at least in your codepen).

Comment: `120x5 > 500`. Change the width of the box elements to 100px or 20%. Then the horizontal scrollbar is due to the vertical scrollbar (`overflow-y`)

Comment: If you couple `height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto` it works normally.

Comment: this is an X-Y problem... you don't need `mainContainer` to be a *grid container*, remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little awkward that you *gridify* everything. Never seen this before.

The reason is: the horizontal takes up a little vertical space. That is then subtracted from the available vertical space. But unfortunately the grid rows don't adopt to that.

I don't have an authoritative answer whether this is the intended behavior or if it is just not defined by W3C and browser vendors do their own stuff.

But here is a workaround (which applies to your case, but might not be applicable for everyone): I wrapped the boxes of container and broke apart responsibilities. Also I used `position: relative` and `absolute`.

```css
html {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.mainContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container-wrap {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <h3>Without horizontal scroll - no vertical scroll bar</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainContainer">
  <h3>With horizontal scroll- vertical scroll is comming</h3>
  <div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```